# Use of 'anymore'

Tags: language-formation

Do we have to use 'anymore' only in the sentences that emphasize negativity?

I can say;

> I don't want to go school anymore

However, can't say this;

> I will always be with you anymore

Comment: Have you looked up *anymore* in a good dictionary for definition and usage?

Comment: It's a negative-polarity item. So what you have amounts to the famous "Je t'aime ! Moi non plus." Which, yes, you can say that. Sing, even. That's not the question. The question is, is that what you actually *want* to say. That you always never will be with them.

Comment: Note that this is analogous to the fact that we normally only use *evermore* in positive statements. So we have (1) *I **don't want** to go to school **anymore*** and (2) *I **want** to go to school **evermore**.*

Comment: Oh thank you Jason, this is what I actually was trying to find out though. My intention was to find out is there any other usage instead of anymore.